# Question about this Simple Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Hello sorry i am a student who sucks at math i do have a father but can't be found nowhere for a simple question to ask i have no one but happy to found this site maybe someone out there could help me explain in a more detail way how this combinatorics works

How many arrangements can be made out of the letters of the word YIELD with the vowels not being separated

possible solution are:

20
24
48
52
58

can anyone explain then to me how it is solve so i can solve the other rest problem i am good at learning it's just that i just need to see a sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the four blocks $Y$, $IE$, $L$ and $D$. These can be arranged in $4! = 24$ ways. Moreover the vowels in the vowels block can be arranged in $2! = 2$ ways. In total there are therefore $2 \cdot 24 = 48$ ways to arrange the letters.

Sometimes we consider $Y$ to be a vowel, in this case the blocks are $YIE$, $L$ and $D$, and a similar calculation yields an answer of $36$, so the problem setter probably did not consider $Y$ as a vowel.

Comment: sir that's nice thank you is it right the way i see it 4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24 then 2! = 2 x 1 = 2..

Comment: @Detective7: Yep.